# Merging two tables with no unique keys without row number

Tags: sql, apache-calcite

I have two tables

**Table A:**

```
Name
----
Andy
Greg
```

**Table B:**

```
Value
-----
1
2
```

I want to merge these two tables into one:

**Table C:**

```
Result
------
Andy 1
Greg 2
```

**Note:-**

without changing the order. I cannot use `row numbers` as I am using `Apache Calcite` and it doesn't support that right now.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you're asking is (strictly speaking) impossible because SQL (and most other query languages and database systems) have no concept of a "natural" row sort-order. Some database systems return rows in the order they're physically in on-disk, but that is not deterministic (e.g. due to DBMS reusing the space used by previously deleted rows) and this behavior cannot be guaranteed (e.g. doing a database GC or internal shrink/defragmentation will change the "natural" order of the rows). This is why you must always specify an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Comment: That said - the example data you've posted seems to already be lexicographical (i.e. alphabetical+numeric) order. Would it work if you did `FROM tableA ORDER BY [Name]` and `FROM tableB ORDER BY [value]`?

Comment: I have edited my answer you can check out................

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH X AS 
(
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT NAME AS Val1,

(SELECT  Count(*) from #TableA a1 WHERE a1.Name < a2.Name) AS myRowNumber1 FROM #TableA a2

)a1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT Id AS Val2,

(SELECT  Count(*) from #TableB a1 WHERE a1.Id < a2.Id) AS myRowNumber2 FROM #TableB a2 
)b1

ON a1.myRowNumber1=b1.myRowNumber2
)

SELECT Val1 +' '+ Val2 AS Result FROM X
```

You can use Count(*) instead of Row_Number()

**OutPut:-**

```
Result
---------

Andy 1

Greg 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column as an identifier

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) AS id
INTO #NAMES
FROM TABLE1

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE) AS id
INTO #VALUES_TABLE
FROM TABLE2
```

And then join by the row number that will be called `id`

```
SELECT *
FROM #NAMES t1
LEFT JOIN #VALUES_TABLE t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Calcite does not have a function exactly like [Oracle's ROWNUM pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) but it does have the standard SQL window function [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm). You can use it as follows:

```
create table a as select * from (values ('Andy'), ('Greg')) as t (name);
create table b as select * from (values (1), (2)) as t (v);

select *
from (select name, row_number() over () as id from a)
join (select v, row_number() over () as id from b)
using (id);

+----+------+---+
| ID | NAME | V |
+----+------+---+
|  1 | Andy | 1 |
|  2 | Greg | 2 |
+----+------+---+
(2 rows)
```

If you want deterministic order, you can change `over ()` to, say, `over (order by name desc)`.